# Load Google Optimize On DataLayer Change - Evaluate on Custom Event

Tags: google-optimize

How can I load google optimize on a dataLayer change or evaluate on a custom event?  The interface has changed and I don't see how to set this up so that:

```
window['dataLayer'].push({'event': 'optimize.activate'});
```

Will work? The targeting requires a page url and also have it set to look for variable optimize contains true.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is still possible. You can find this option at the very bottom of the page, within the Settings block. It is called 'Activation event', and you can select Page load or Custom event. The second one is which you are looking for.

As you have mentioned, you still need to provide at least one rule, that refers to some URL settings.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't see that option before and couldn't find it in any docs.